# Recursive function returning empty arrray

Tags: javascript

I am having issue with my recursive function `getPath`, as it is returning an empty array, when it should be returning an array that looks something like this:

```
['main', 'children', 'name']
```

I am not sure if the logic pare is right, as that isn't what the question is about, the question is, why is my array empty? It is pushing data onto the array, but the final result is an empty array.

```js
let dataScope = [{
  "name": "main",
  "location": [":data"]
}, {
  "name": "child",
  "location": ["main", "children"]
}]

function getLocation(key) {
  let val = dataScope.find(i => i.name == key)
  return val ? val.location : []
}

function getPath(items) {
  let path = []
  let item = items.shift()
  if (item) {
    let loc = getLocation(item)
    if (loc.length > 0 && loc.join('.') != ':data') {
      path.push(...getPath(loc))
      console.log('added to array')
    }
  }
  return path
}

console.log(getPath(['child', 'name']))
```

Comment: well, your first item fails the test, therefore you never recurse

Comment: are you sure? `added to array` is printed out...

Comment: hmmm, it is too! something else must be wrong then

Comment: Why not put a `console.log(path)` before your `added to array` loc then?

Comment: @JaromandaX, the first item checked is `child`, which should not fail

Comment: oh yeah, didn't read that correctly :p

Comment: Please note that each recursive "iteration" will have it's own instance of `path[]` array due to the nature of variables declared using `let`.

Comment: but `getPath(['child', 'name'])` ... there is nothing with name "name", and even if you change that to `main`, there's still nothing that will get added to the array

Comment: I am trying to make a templating tool, basically I am working on the loops. I have an object with data in it, and I am trying to build a path to that data. Example: `{a: { b: { c: 'Hello'}}}`. in the template I am trying to get the path to `c` for example. `<div for="item in a"><div for="item2 in item">{{item2.c}}</div></div>`. In the end `item2` references `item` which references `a` to make `['a', 'b', 'c']` instead of `['item', 'item2', 'c']` if that makes sense...

Comment: you seem to have forgotten to actually do anything with `loc`

Comment: @JaromandaX it is getting passed to the recursive function. the result is then pushed onto the path

Comment: NB: modifying the input parameter as you do when you call `items.shift()` is a sure way to end up with a recursive function that doesn't work the way you expect it do.   Better to work on a copy of that array than on the passed reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do anything with `loc` so, it seems nothing gets pushed to the array

Note: I'm still trying to get to grips with why your original code results in an empty array - however, this code produces the expected result :p

```js
let dataScope = [{
  "name": "main",
  "location": [":data"]
}, {
  "name": "child",
  "location": ["main", "children"]
}]

function getLocation(key) {
  let val = dataScope.find(i => i.name == key);
  return val ? val.location : []
}

function getPath(items, indent = 0) {
  let z = items.join(',');
  console.log(`${' '.repeat(indent)}called with ${z}`);
  let path = [];
  let item = items.shift();
  let loc = [];
  if (item) {
    loc = getLocation(item);
    if (loc.length > 0 && loc.join('.') != ':data') {
      path.push(...getPath(loc.slice(), indent + 4)); // .slice() so loc isn't mutated
      console.log(`${' '.repeat(indent)}${z} has path [${path.join(',')}]`);
    }
    path.push(...loc); // add loc to the path - comment this out to see the difference
  }
  console.log(`${' '.repeat(indent)}${z} returns [${path.join(',')}]`);
  return path
}

console.log(`[${getPath(['child', 'name'])}]`)
```

Comment: I changed yours a little by just pushing loc to the array then calling `getPath(loc)` afterwards without pushing that to the array, and that seems to work.

Comment: why?? doesn't that produce a different result *order*? (I don't really know what you changed though)

Comment: I changed `path.push(...getPath(loc))` to `path.push(...loc);getPath(loc)`

Comment: won't that result in `[main,children,:data]` - not what you expected, right?

Comment: It seems to work when I do that. I also need to push what is left of the `items` array to the end of the `path[]`, which I did after the `if`, and I am now getting `[main,children,name]`, which looks closer to what I want for the final result. (now that I can visualize the output :))

Answer (score 0):

First youre passing an array of names to getPath but then later youre passing the location array. Which one should it be? Logic needs tweaking. And also there's nothing in the dataset using the value "name" so your test is incorrect as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're doing recursion sending dataScope `location` but you implemented `getPath` expecting dataScope `keys`:

```js
let dataScope = [{
  "name": "main",
  "location": [":data"]
}, {
  "name": "child",
  "location": ["main", "children"]
}]

function getLocation(key) {
  let val = dataScope.find(i => i.name == key)
  return val ? val.location : []
}

function getPath(keys) { // changing items name to keys for clarification
  let path = []
  let key = keys.shift()
  if (key) {
    let loc = getLocation(key);
    if (loc.length > 0 && loc.join('.') != ':data') {
      path.push(...loc) // push locs into array
      getPath(keys) // call getPath with remaining keys
      console.log('added to array')
    }
  }
  return path
}

console.log(getPath(['child', 'main']))
```

You will not have `:data` into your `path` result because of this statement: `loc.join('.') != ':data'`. If you remove it you will get your expected output.